# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Float64Array')

Tags: angular, types, migration, undefined, angular13

I am migrating an Angular app from v12 to v13 and I experienced the following error:

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Float64Array')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Float64Array')
    at setupTypedArray (dsp.js:60:14)
    at 18127 (dsp.js:77:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 3015 (logs-preview.component.ts:10:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 75649 (alarm-preview.component.ts:19:14)
    at Function.__webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:25694:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:371:52)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1165:17)
    at zone.js:1278:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25681:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
```

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvSPH.png)

The app is running in a Docker container. I entered the container using
`docker exec -it [NAME_OF_CONTAINER] /bin/sh`

Then I navigated to the project root folder and updated Angular via the cli:
`npm run-script ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13 @angular/cdk@13 ...`

I also updated several related packages from the npm Angular repositories, as can be seen in my package.json. Some of them via Angular cli, others via changes directly to package.json.

I'm quite new to migration so I may have easily updated a package to a wrong version or missed a package. Here's my current package.json:

```
{
  "name": "name-of-app",
  "version": "0.96.17",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "ng build --configuration production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^13.4.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "5.0.2",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.1.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^13.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^20.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-graph": "^8.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "d3": "^3.5.17",
    "dsp.js": "^1.0.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "libmseedjs": "^1.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^12.0.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^13.0.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^13.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.4.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^10.1.2",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^13.0.0",
    "@types/canvasjs": "^1.9.6",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.13",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.34",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^4.0.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.6.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the app run properly in v12 environment?

Comment: Yes v12 runs without errors. Maybe it's noteworthy to mention that I already migrated from v10 to v11, and from v11 to v12.

Comment: Ever got it fixed? I have the same issue